# Silverstripe template i18n translation

Tags: internationalization, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I'm trying to use i18n functionality in templates in Silverstripe.

In a template **ss file**, I have the following:

```
<h4 class="red-underline"><%t Namespace1.Replace "ToBeReplaced" %></h4>
```

And I have the following in **/lang/en_US.yml**:

```
en:
  Namespace1:
    Replace: 'ReplacedString'
```

I have also added this to my **_config.php**:

```
use SilverStripe\i18n\i18n;
i18n::set_locale('en_US');
```

And this in my **config.yml**:

```
SilverStripe\i18n\i18n:
  common_locales:
    en_US:
      name: English (USA)
      native: English
```

But the string "ToBeReplaced" is not replaced. 
The documentation I can find about this, is:
https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/i18n/

**Am I missing something?**

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the lang folder was added to the wrong location.

It should be located in **/mysite/lang/**